# Unable to list image files in the ApplicationDocumentsDirectory even though I can load/display them

Tags: android, flutter, image, io, path-provider

I'm trying to get a list of files in my app's documents directory using `path_provider` and `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()` along with `Directory(appFolder).listSync()` from `dart:io`. While I can load the image files from this directory and view them using flutter's `Image.file` function, I cannot see any of the image/jpg files generated by my app in the directory listing. I've also tried loading the files using `File(imagePath)` with the same result.

I cannot understand why `Image.File(imagePath)` can find, load and display the image file successfully while running `File(imagePath)` gives an `OS Error: No such file or directory` . For additional context - these files are being generated using the `camera` package for flutter. I'm seeing this on Android so far (have not testing this on iOS yet).

*Code previews*

Code to get appFolder in both cases

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

final dbFolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

Code to display the images

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// just the relevant code to display the image
Center(
  child: Image.file(Platform.isIOS
     ? File(appFolder + '/' + imagePath)
     : File(appFolder + imagePath)),
),
```

Code to list the files in the folder

```
  import 'dart:io';

  void _getDirectoryList() async {
    fileList = Directory(appFolder).listSync(followLinks: true);
    final List<FileSystemEntity> entities =
        await Directory(appFolder).list().toList();
    entities.forEach(print);
  }
```

I'm doing all this to create an archive of the app db and user generated image files, but have gotten stuck at not finding the user-generated image files in the `ApplicationDocumentsDirectory`.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Look at what 'print' in entities.forEach does. If you are trying to print the  names of the files you want to use debugPrint(item)

```
void _getDirectoryList() async {
  fileList = 
    Directory(appFolder).listSync(followLinks: true);
    final List<FileSystemEntity> entities =
      await Directory(appFolder).list().toList();
    entities.forEach((item) => debugPrint(item.toString());
}
```

Look into [debugPrint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/debugPrint.html) and [forEach](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) to learn more about what is going wrong.